# Vagrant + Mesos : /etc/mesos/zk does not change

Tags: vagrant, apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere

Im trying to automate my mesos cluster with only vagrant (so no chef, puppet, ansible or whatever). 
The vagrantfile I now have does not modify /etc/mesos/zk. I've tried to echo it in with `cmd: "echo zk://192.168.3.2:2181,192.168.3.3:2181/mesos > /etc/mesos/zk"` and `srv.vm.provision "shell", inline: "docker exec -t mesoscloud-mesos-master 'echo zk://192.168.3.2:2181,192.168.3.3:2181/mesos > /etc/mesos/zk"`  but non of those work. Maybe the MESOS_ZK variable is used wrong, but I am out of ideas. This is (the relevant part) of my Vagrantfile:

```html
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :this

require 'fileutils'
require 'yaml'

servers = YAML.load_file('servers.yml')

$HOST_IP_1='192.168.3.2'
$HOST_IP_2='192.168.3.3'


Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 config.ssh.insert_key = false
 config.ssh.forward_agent = true
 # config.vm.provision "docker"
 servers.each do |server|
  config.vm.define server["name"] do |srv|
   srv.vm.box_check_update = false
   srv.vm.hostname = server["name"]
   srv.vm.box = "centos/7" 
   srv.vm.network "private_network", ip: server["priv_ip"]
   srv.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en2: Thunderbolt 1", ip: server["pub_ip"]
   srv.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
   if srv.vm.hostname == "melisandre"

    # ZOOKEEPER
    srv.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
     d.run "mesoscloud/zookeeper",
      args: "--net='host' -e SERVER_ID=1 -e ADDITIONAL_ZOOKEEPER_1=server.1=192.168.3.2:2888:3888 -e ADDITIONAL_ZOOKEEPER_2=server.2=192.168.3.3:2888:3888"
    end


    # MESOS-MASTER
    srv.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
     d.run "mesoscloud/mesos-master",
      args: "--net='host' -p 5050:5050 -e MESOS_HOSTNAME=192.168.3.2 -e MESOS_IP=192.168.3.2 -e MESOS_ZK='zk://192.168.3.2:2181,192.178.3.3:2181/mesos' -e MESOS_PORT=5050 -e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos -e MESOS_QUORUM=1 -e MESOS_REGISTRY=in_memory -e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/mesos"#,cmd: "echo zk://192.168.3.2:2181,192.168.3.3:2181/mesos > /etc/mesos/zk"

    end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the `cmd` of a `docker run` execution it disables the default command. So you'd have to make it a compound command (joined with `;` or `&&`) that also does what the default command does.

That said, you should probably be using the mesosphere docker images (https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/mesos-master and https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/mesos-slave) instead of the deprecated mesoscloud ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a preconfigured Vagrant solution (which can be adapted), have a look at [tobilg/coreos-mesos-cluster](https://github.com/tobilg/coreos-mesos-cluster).

By default, this will launch a 3 node CoreOS cluster with ZooKeeper, Mesos Masters & Slaves and Marathon.